# How to set expire a link after one time click in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

If i send a link and someone open it then that link is not in used anymore.How can we do this?

Comment: Use Page counter in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could do that with Javascript `Closures`,

In your html ,

```
<a href="#" id="myButton" title="">Click Me!</a>
```

And in your js,

```
(function(){
    var click_counter = 0;
    $('#myButton').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = jQuery(this);
        click_counter += 1;
        if (!el.hasClass('inactive')){
            // should be activated
            alert('You have clicked the link ' + click_counter + ' once , And this will be disabled');
        };
        if (click_counter >= 1){
            // deactivate
            el.addClass('inactive');
        };
    });
})();
```

And to indicate your button has been clicked , add this class to your CSS

```
a.inactive {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you but can u give me some suggestion to expire a link in 48 hours

Comment: @user3440874 if the above code works for you , kindly mark it as the answer so that it would help others to identify